# Are Docker images full operating systems? Containers VS Virtual Machines

Tags: docker

There are images on docker registry which have names like `ubuntu` or `redhat`. Do these images run the complete operating system or they only contain the utilities that come with the operating system?

I thought Docker uses host operating system and the docker image should not be running the operating system. Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 3):

`Docker containers` wrap a piece of software in a complete `filesystem` that contains everything needed to run: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries – anything that can be installed on a server.

Like `FreeBSD Jails` and `Solaris Zones`, `Linux containers` are self-contained execution environments -- with their own, isolated CPU, memory, block I/O, and network resources (Using `CGROUPS` kernel feature) -- that **share the kernel of the host operating system**. The result is something that feels like a `virtual Machine`, but sheds all the weight and startup overhead of a guest operating system.

This being said Each distribution has it's own official `docker` image (`library`), that is shipped with minimal binaries, Considered `docker`'s best practices and it's ready to build on.

Example:

If you use `debian base image` you will have `apt` as your package manager, and `debian` repositories at your disposal.

In contrast if you use `centos base image`, you will have `yum` with `centos` packages at your disposal.

Please note that the above example is only to shed some light on the matter and does not include all the differences.